# Python processing CSV

Tags: python, pandas

```
input('/mpg-Kevin_Mulach.csv')

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('http://www.ishelp.info/data/insurance.csv')
for row in pd(data, 10): 
        print(row['age'], row['sex'], row['bmi'], row['children'], row['smoker'], row['region'], row['charges'])
```

Question: How would I show the first 10 records when I print?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pd.head(10)`. Just change `pd` by the actual data frame that you want to print.